# Bootstrap for estimating parameters with only one sample

Tags: estimation, bootstrap

Let say we have only one sample in which we are interested only on one statistics c of this sample. This is usually true in practice when we usually have only one data set. So, most probably the usual estimating method like MLE cant be applied.

And let say we want to estimate 2 parameters (i.e. a & b) of a certain dist which depend on c. Is bootstrap technique will work for this? Is there any theoretical proof for such practice?

Any help will be appreciated.

tsukiko